# ::boost::spirit: +alnum_p and hyphen

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

Right now I have this boost::spirit pattern:

```
        str_p("url(") >> !( str_p("'") | str_p("\"") ) >> ("#") >>
        ((+alnum_p)[assign_a(o_rPaintUri)] >> 
        !( str_p("'") | str_p("\"") ) >> str_p(")")
```

That works fine to parse things like `url(#myRadialGradient)`, however it doesn't work if there's a hyphen like `url(#my-RadialGradient4)`.
I've tried things like `(+alnum_p | '-')[assign_a(o_rPaintUri)]` but it isn't working.

Anybody has a hint how it can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's Spirit Classic (aka. v1.x). 
<sup>PS. *No clue, but you could try `(+(alnum_p | ch_p('-')))` instead of  `(+alnum_p | '-')`*</sup>

You should get to this century, and use Spirit V2 (roughly ten years since it superseded v1):

### Spirit V2

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a78dc18095c7ed4c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

int main() {
    for (std::string const sample : {
            "url(#myRadialGradient)",
            "url(#my-RadialGradient4)",
            "url('#my-RadialGradient4')",
            "url(\"#my-RadialGradient4\")",
            })
    {
        std::cout << " -- parsing '" << sample << "'\n";
        std::string o_rPaintUri;

        bool ok;
        {
            using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
            ok = parse(sample.begin(), sample.end(),
                    "url(" >> -char_("'\"") >> "#" >> +(alnum|char_('-')) >> -char_("'\"") >> ")",
                    o_rPaintUri);
        }

        if (ok)
            std::cout << "Parsed: '" << o_rPaintUri << "'\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
-- parsing 'url(#myRadialGradient)'
Parsed: 'myRadialGradient'
-- parsing 'url(#my-RadialGradient4)'
Parsed: 'my-RadialGradient4'
-- parsing 'url('#my-RadialGradient4')'
Parsed: ''my-RadialGradient4''
-- parsing 'url("#my-RadialGradient4")'
Parsed: '"my-RadialGradient4"'
```

### Spirit X3

Same, but replace `qi` with `x3`. I'd suggest some improvements:

- now support any characters withing quotes (except the quote char)
- now expect all syntax elements and report useful errors

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af82c690d7412d87)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

int main() {
    for (std::string const sample : {
            "url(#myRadialGradient)",
            "url(#my-RadialGradient4)",
            "url('#my-RadialGradient4')",
            "url(\"#my-RadialGradient4\")",
            // extra
            "url('#my-RadialGradient4\")",
            "url('#my-Radial_Gradient4')",
            "url('#my-Radial_Gradient4'",
            "url(oops)",
            "url('oops')",
            "url(\"oops\")",
            "oops",
            })
    {
        std::cout << " -- parsing " << sample << "\n";
        std::string o_rPaintUri;

        bool ok = false;
        try {
            using namespace x3;

            auto q = [](auto quote) { return quote > as_parser('#') > *(char_ - quote) > quote; };

            auto u = rule<struct url, std::string> { "#anchor|'#anchor'|\"#anchor\"" } // FOR ERROR INFO ONLY
                   = q("'") | q('"') | '#' >> *~char_(')');

            ok = parse(sample.begin(), sample.end(), eps > "url(" > u > ")", o_rPaintUri);

            if (ok)
                std::cout << "Parsed: '" << o_rPaintUri << "'\n";
            else
                std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        } catch (x3::expectation_failure<std::string::const_iterator> const& e) {
            std::cout << "    Error: '" << std::string(e.where(), sample.end()) << "', expecting " << e.which() << "\n";
        }

    }
}
```

Prints

```
-- parsing url(#myRadialGradient)
Parsed: 'myRadialGradient'
-- parsing url(#my-RadialGradient4)
Parsed: 'my-RadialGradient4'
-- parsing url('#my-RadialGradient4')
Parsed: 'my-RadialGradient4'
-- parsing url("#my-RadialGradient4")
Parsed: 'my-RadialGradient4'
-- parsing url('#my-RadialGradient4")
    Error: '', expecting "'"
-- parsing url('#my-Radial_Gradient4')
Parsed: 'my-Radial_Gradient4'
-- parsing url('#my-Radial_Gradient4'
    Error: '', expecting ')'
-- parsing url(oops)
    Error: 'oops)', expecting #anchor|'#anchor'|"#anchor"
-- parsing url('oops')
    Error: 'oops')', expecting '#'
-- parsing url("oops")
    Error: 'oops")', expecting '#'
-- parsing oops
    Error: 'oops', expecting "url("
```

Comment: Hi sehe, thanks for the detailed answer, it has been really helpful. I've just realized that the url might contain an hyphen or other punctuation marks. I've tried something like +(alnum| punct ) but it's not working. Do you know how I could do it with Spirit::qi without doing +(alnum|char_('-')|char_('_')|char_(',').... ?

Comment: @user2035548 Do exactly as my answer already shows in the X3 sample (_"now support any characters withing quotes (except the quote char)"_)?. Hint: `('"' >> *~char_('"') >> '"')`. [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char.html#spirit.qi.reference.char.char.expression_semantics)